# Do I ever have to worry that "no shell will be available" to execute a system command?

Tags: c

The manual page "man system" contains the following section:

> - If  command  is  NULL, then a nonzero value if a shell is available, or 0 if no shell is available.

which basically indicates that I can check with 
`if(system(NULL) != 0) {foo;}` if a shell is currently available or not.

When do I have to consider to do so? Because I never ever got an error which was related to this specific case.

Comment: Also from [`man system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html): "*[...] even though POSIX.1-2001 requires a conforming implementation to provide a shell, that shell may not be available or executable if the calling program has previously called [chroot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html) [...]*"

Comment: oh sorry, i missed that part, thank you

Comment: In my experience, it is very rarely a problem.  There are circumstances where it could happen; if you want to head off problems, you could check.  Note that POSIX assumes that you'll have a POSIX-compliant shell; the C standard merely says a 'command processor'.  There's no guarantee about which notations the command processor or shell will accept — it might not be Bash, for example.  So it depends on how much you want to worry.  In practice, I wouldn't worry much about it, but I also don't tend to call `system` very often so it usually doesn't hurt me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also from [`man system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html):

> [...] even though POSIX.1-2001 requires a conforming implementation to provide a shell, that shell may not be available or executable if the calling program has previously called [chroot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html) [...]

So that's a possible case where `/bin/sh` might not be available. In practice I wouldn't worry too much about it. (But then again, I probably wouldn't use `system` in real code in the first place.)